# How to extract string constants for localization with i18next (node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, localization, i18next

I have several javascript source files (.js) that use string constants to provide readable output to the user. Here's an example (though I have tons of constants per file, not just a couple):

```
const WELCOME_MESSAGE = 'Welcome %!';
const GOODBYE_MESSAGE = 'Goodbye';
```

I'm using *i18next* and *i18next-sprintf-postprocessor* to provide localized versions for these strings. I place localized versions in a directory structure like this one:

```
├── i18n/    // localized strings
│   ├── en.js
│   ├── de.js
│   ├── fr.js
│   ├── it.js
│   └── es.js
├── node_modules/
│   └── ...  // npm modules
└── index.js // main js file
```

Each localized file looks more or less like this (en.js example shown below):

```
// en.js
module.exports = {
    translation: {
        WELCOME_MESSAGE: 'Welcome %!',
        GOODBYE_MESSAGE: 'Goodbye'
    }
}
```

Since I have several source files and tons of strings constants in English I want to generate *en.js* (above) automatically via a *gulp* process that extracts all the string constants from the source file (*index.js*) and creates the file above (*en.js*, previously creating the *i18n* directory if it doesn't exist).

I have been searching for a solution to no avail (would love to use an existing npm package to do this if available). I have found i18next scanners and parsers but they expect the file to support i18next already (eg. string used via the `_t` function).

Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: There's a problem. how do you intend to differentiate between text intended for localization and general-purpose string constants? You can use a lexer or just parse them with regexps.

Comment: Please assume **all** text constants in CAPITALS have to be localized

Comment: Considering that there's a convention to name constants in capitals, this may not be useful. It depends on your project. You know how things are done there, others don't. I'd go with regexps and double check a list of matched constants before replacing them.